# Use routing in HTTPHandler

Tags: asp.net, routes, httphandler

I want to use HTTP Handler in order to create a RSS feeds.

For the purpose, I want to put my logic for creating the rss XML in C# class, which implement IHttpHandler, then to "map" this handler into the web.config file and to register the "mapped name" in my routing rules. I am doing something like this:

My HTTPHanlder:

```
public class RSSFeedHandler:IHttpHandler  
{   
    public void ProcessRequest( HttpContext context )  
    {   
        //logic for building the XML   
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";   
        context.Response.Write( XMLContent);   
        .....................................
```

My Web.Config:

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add path="Rss" verb="*" type="RSSFeedHandler" validate="false" />
.......   
<handlers> 
  <add name="RSSFeedHandler" path="Rss" verb="*" type="RSSFeedHandler" />
   ........
```

My Routing rulse in global.asax:

```
RoutingHandler rssHandler = new RoutingHandler( "~/rss" );   
 .........   
 routes.Add( new Route( "rss/{type}/{id}", rssHandler ) );
```

My Routing Hanlder:

```
public class RoutingHandler : IRouteHandler    
{  
    ............................   
    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler( RequestContext requestContext )   
    {
```

So, I want when in the address bar, the user types something like: www.mysite.com/rss/news/25 for example,
the server to execute the logic from the HTTP Handler and to show the rss feed for type 'news' with id '25'. (these routing parameters should be parsed into my RSS HTTPHanlder)

The problem is, that, when I am calling an URL similar to the one above, there is an ERROR in GetHttpHandler method, which says: "The file '/Rss' does not exist."

I think, that this is because, this method has been invoked before the 'mapping' in web.config, but I am not sure.

Do you know how can I achieve the funcionality that I want?

Comment: Are you running this in the Visual Studio's integrated web server or in IIS (if IIS which version)?

Comment: I highly doubt it, but could you uncapitalize the `Rss` in the web.configs (i know windows is case-insensitive directories but just for clarity)

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2008 and it's integrated IIS. But I am having other HTTPHanndlers in my project which are "mapped" in the web.config and they working. The routing logic is also correct. I am having and a lot of routing rules that are OK. If I disable the routing pattern with 'routes.Add( new Route( "Rss", new StopRoutingHandler() ) )', this handler is called, but the I can't get the routing parameters from it.

Comment: In the project source, I am using only lower case everywhere where I need to use the word 'rss'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem.

All I needed is to return a RSSFeedHandler in the GetHttpHandler method instead a page.

You can preview http://forums.asp.net/p/1533299/3717070.aspx for more information about the solution.